# make whole row clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i'm new on react(hooks) typescript, trying to learn by doing,
here i have created antd table(which works), on the right side of table is 'Edit' it is clickable and works well, but my question is how to make each row clickable instead of that 'Edit' ? like i could click anywhere on the row and it should take me to its 'Edit' link instead of me clicking just on 'Edit':
[image]

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
const { t } = useTranslation();



const columns = [
    {
      title: t("tilaus.state"),
      dataIndex: "state",
      key: "state",
      render: (value: OrderState) => (
        <span className="material-icons">
   
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: t("request.parcelId"),
      dataIndex: "parcelId",
      key: "parcelId",
    },
    {
      title: t("request.date"),
      dataIndex: "date",
      key: "date",
      render: (value: Date) => <div>{value.toLocaleDateString("af-AF")}</div>,
    },
    {
      title: t("request.sender"),
      dataIndex: "sender",
      key: "sender",
      render: (value: CustomerDto) => <div>{value.name}</div>,
    },
    {
      title: t("request.recipient"),
      dataIndex: "recipient",
      key: "recipient",
      render: (value: CustomerDto) => <div>{value.name}</div>,
    },
    {
      title: t("request.price"),
      dataIndex: "price",
      key: "price",
    },
    {
      title: "",
      dataIndex: "id",
      key: "id",
      render: (value: string) => (
        <Link to={"details/" + value}>{t("request.edit")}</Link>
      ),
    },
  ];



      <Table
            
            dataSource={orders}
            columns={columns}
            pagination={false}
            scroll={{ x: true }}
            onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
              return {
                onClick: (event) => {
                  handleClick(record);
                },
              };
            }}
          />
```

Comment: where is Table coming from? I can help but looks like the problem's with the Table component

Comment: @TimGivois table is antd table

Comment: @TimGivois this is the edit part ' render: (value: string) => (
        <Link to={"details/" + value}>{t("request.edit")}</Link>
      ),' how to make that work on whole row

Comment: you actually can't. HTML rows can't have links. But you can do a workaround (find my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using ant.d [table](https://ant.design/components/table/). I've grabbed one of the examples and console logged the output. You can find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/s1xds?file=/index.js to show you how the onclick in the entire row is being triggered.

For your specific thing, you need to change `onRow` prop. You can't add a Link directly to the row, but you can use `history` from react-router (if you are using it, docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)) or directly mutate the URL when onclick is called.

So in your case, you'll have to do this:

```
<Table
            
            dataSource={orders}
            columns={columns}
            pagination={false}
            scroll={{ x: true }}
            onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
              return {
                onClick: (event) => {
                  history.push(`/details/${record.id}`);
                },
              };
            }}
          />
```

or

```
<Table
            
            dataSource={orders}
            columns={columns}
            pagination={false}
            scroll={{ x: true }}
            onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
              return {
                onClick: (event) => {
                  window.location.href = `${window.location.href}/details/${record.id}`
                },
              };
            }}
          />
```

Comment: I've updated the solution. In general terms, this is what you should do. I can't actually do it for you as I don't have the code. I could do it if you share a codesandbox.

Comment: Could you possibly show how to add search input to it, with react hooks typescript, been whole day trying to implement it...

Comment: yes! you can go and ask the question and I'll be happy to answer it :)

Comment: could you answer this one, it is same as mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692690/antd-table-search-filtering/66693113#66693113