# antd table search filtering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, html-table

i'm new on react hooks(typescript), here i'm having trouble figuring out how to filter by two, at the moment search filtering is working with one filter and it is 'receiver?.name?'
i want to add one more filter and it is 'sending?name?'

here is working code:

```js
 const handleSearchh = (searchText: string) => {
    const filteredEvents = orders?.filter(({ receiver }) => {
      const name = receiver?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
      return name.includes(searchText);
    });

    setData(filteredEvents);
  };


<Searchh onSearch={handleSearchh} />



 <Table
 dataSource={Data}
 columns={columns}
 />
```

i want to add this to it

```js
 const filteredEvents = orders?.filter(({ sending }) => {
      const name = sending?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
      return name.includes(searchText);
    });
```

it is antd table i want it to filter the search by two parameters , receivers and senders name

Comment: do you want to filter by sending AND receiver or by sending OR receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
  const handleSearchh = (searchText: string) => {
    filterData(searchText)
  };

 const filterData = (searchText) => {     
    const filteredEvents = orders?.filter(({ receiver, sending }) => {
     const receiverName = receiver?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
     const sendingName = sending?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
     return receiverName.includes(searchText) && sendingName.includes(searchText);
   });

   setData(filteredEvents);    
 }
```

Comment: return receiverName.includes(searchText) && name.sendingName(searchText);
Property 'sendingName' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

Comment: I edited my code,  just a typo error in sendingName(searchText).

Comment: Boutahil now  ' sendingName(searchText);'  This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: i did fix your mistake, but it is not filtering anything...

Comment: it gives you 0 elements or bug?

Comment: it gives 0 elements

Comment: So maybe there is no item matches your filter!
you need to verify if there is an item verify this condition sending name and receiver name must include your search text.

Comment: as i said this is working perfectly :  const handleSearchh = (searchText: string) => {
    const filteredEvents = orders?.filter(({ receiver }) => {
      const name = receiver?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
      return name.includes(searchText);
    });

    setData(filteredEvents);
  };

Comment: Yes so we added a condition to verify if sendingName contain searchText.

Comment: it is not filtering both, when user writes something it should check both of those instead of one

Comment: lol if you removed   receiverName.includes(searchText) and it works, and you test again by removing sendingName.includes(searchText) and it works again, so the fusion should work! plz verify this alone sendingName.includes(searchText);

Comment: i got it working with this '||' and removing '&&', what is the point of 'searchText' ? is it needed ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't antd specific, but can't you just chain the filter functions?

```js
// ...
const filterFuncOne = ({ receiver }) => {
      const name = receiver?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
      return name.includes(searchText);
    };

const filterFuncTwo = ({ sending }) => {
      const name = sending?.name?.toLowerCase() ?? "";
      return name.includes(searchText);
    }

const filteredEvents = orders? 
  .filter.(filterFuncOne)
  .filter(filterFuncTwo);  // <-- chained

//...
```

Comment: Binding element 'receiver ' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031), when i add any to it then it cant find 'Cannot find name 'receiver '.ts(2304)'

Comment: Thats a typescript "warning" saying the function argument isn't typed.  You can type the function correctly, turn it off in your `ts-config`, or `ts-ignore` the warning.  One example of typing it can be like this: `({receiver}: {receiver: any})`.  If you do: `({receiver: any})` which is what I think you must be doing to get the error you just described, it will rename receiver to any which means `receiver` can't be found.